# Subrings of rings of quotients

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Take a noncommutative noetherian domain $R$ and a multiplicative subset $X$ (say just non zero elements of $R$). The standard construction gives a ring of quotients $RX{}^{-1}$, and I am looking at modules over $RX{}^{-1}$. From these module constructions we can define a certain subring $S$ with $R\subseteq S \subset RX{}^{-1}$. Now $S$ depends on the construction, and in particular it is not obvious whether $R=S$ in various cases, but I have questions about the subring in general:

1) Is there a classification of the subrings $S$?

2) Are there any standard methods to show when $S$ is itself a noetherian domain?

3) Is there any criterion which can be used to determine when $S=R$?

One thing which can be assumed about the $S$ which I have is that they do not contain any $x{}^{-1}$ for which $x\in X$ was not already invertible in $R$.

Basically I am asking if anyone has looked at the classification or properties of subrings $R\subseteq S \subset RX{}^{-1}$ in any detail. My guess is probably, and I apologies in advance for not being an expert in ring theory (the motivation comes from $C^*$ algebras).

Comment: I don't think that there is a classification for the general case even if $R$ is commutative. But the classification is easy if $R$ is a PID.